# user mode permission denied to bind to socket

Tags: c, sockets, ioctl

In user mode [non-root] on a linux machine, I am trying to bind a socket by using a `ioctl(iInterfaceSocket, SIOCSIFADDR, &stCommand)`. I am getting `error 13 -> Permission denied because of user mode`. If change from usermode to kernel mode everything works fine.

I need to bind the socket in user mode only.  Please suggest a solution while explaining the problem above.  If I missed any information please let me know and I will provide more info.

Comment: @user736403 - what precisely are you trying to achieve? `SIOCSIFADDR` doesn't bind a socket, `bind()` does. `SIOCSIFADDR` sets the address of the machine's network interface.

Comment: Just a small nitpick: running a program as root is very different than running in kernel mode. Programs run as root still run in user mode most of the time; they just have elevated privileges. All processes (root or not) switch between user and kernel mode when they make system calls like `ioctl`.

Answer (score 8):

You can't set the interface address unless you are root (well, technically, unless you have `CAP_NET_ADMIN`). See [devinet.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/devinet.c#L635).

The solution is to run as root. How to implement that solution, whether to make your entire program SUID, or ask the user to run it via [sudo](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) or [gksudo](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gksudo), or whether to factor your program into two parts (root and non-root), that choice is up to you.